# cURL and proxies issue

Tags: php, curl, proxy

I have a script that connects to a page using cURL and a proxy to retrieve information on a daily basis.

Running on my local machine, it connects fine and retrieves the data. When I attempt to run the same script from a Hostgator server it fails to work (returning a 400 error) using the same proxy, or even no proxy at all.

So far I've spent hours trying to figure this out as

1) Other urls work fine, so I know it isn't necessarily a PHP setup issue or proxy issue

2) When trying to access the URL through Yahoo's YQL headerless browser I get an error on either the local or remote server - Query syntax error(s) [line 1:88 mismatched character ' ' expecting '"']"

3) The page will open fine using file_get_contents (as opposed to cURL) on both the local machine and the remote server.

My only theory so far is that the server I'm trying to connect to can see both the local IP and primary IP (the one of the proxy), and blocks a request when it originates from a specific local IP but only when using a proxy - this seems seriously far fetched though?!

Does anyone have an idea why using cURL and a proxy on a Hostgator VPS would return a 400 error whilst the same code and proxy would work on my local machine?

Comment: What do you mean by `Other urls work fine, so I know it isn't necessarily a PHP setup issue or proxy issue` ? Other URLs from your website work well, or other URLs used in cURL work ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant if I try to access www.exampleA.com or www.exampleB.com it connects without error. Only when I try to access this specific URL do I get the 400 code and only on the remote Hostgator VPS.

Comment: If it is related to a very specific URL, can you give us this URL and your PhP code ? If you say it only appears when doing it from Hostgator, I guess you should check their support ?

Comment: I think I've just worked out what causing the issue. When I remove the line "CURLOPT_USERAGENT=> "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 GTB5"," from my options array, it works fine. I don't understand why it doesn't work when I'm on the VPS but does when I'm on localhost?